# Java Generics and reflection!

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class UploadBean {


    protected UploadBean(Map<String,?> map){ 
        //do nothing.
    }
}
```

To use reflection and create a object by invoking the corresponding constructor, I wrote code as follows:

```
Class<?> parTypes[] = new Class<?>[1];
parTypes[0] = Map.class;
Constructor ct = format.getMappingBean().getConstructor(parTypes);
Object[] argList  = new Object[1];
argList[0] = map;
Object retObj = ct.newInstance(argList);
```

This code fails at runtime with "No Such Method Exception".
Now, how do I set the param type correctly?! such that the generic map argument in the constructor is identified?

Comment: Format is an implementation of this: 

public interface FormatFactory {

 public Map<String, Class> getFormat();
 public Class<? extends UploadBean> getMappingBean();
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor is protected - if you make it public *or* use `getDeclaredConstructor` instead of `getConstructor` it should work.

(You'll need to use `setAccessible` if you're trying to call this from somewhere you wouldn't normally have access.)

EDIT: Here's a test to show it working okay:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UploadBean {

    // "throws Exception" just for simplicity. Not nice normally!
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> parTypes[] = new Class<?>[1];
        parTypes[0] = Map.class;
        Constructor ct = UploadBean.class.getDeclaredConstructor(parTypes);
        Object[] argList  = new Object[1];
        argList[0] = null;
        Object retObj = ct.newInstance(argList);
    }

    protected UploadBean(Map<String,?> map){ 
        //do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use getDeclaredConstructor(), as I just found out (but too late!).

Comment: doesn't work 
throws this exception again: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.fileupload.XYZUploadBean.<init>(java.util.Map)

Comment: Would getDeclaredConstructor() then require setAccessible(true)? In my tests it doesn't, but I didn't try separating main() from the UploadBean.

Comment: @Jay: Please provide a short but *complete* program then. If you're using the right class and it's got the right constructor, it should be okay. It works in my tests.

Comment: In particular, does XYZUploadBean have the right constructor? You've shown UploadBean, but not XYZUploadBean...

Answer (score 1):

The generic information is not available at runtime, it's just for static analysis, so do it as if the generics didn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, the error really has nothing to do with generics; this is really just a reflection question. (But it's nice to clarify this point.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call

```
ct.setAccessible(true)
```

The setAccessible method allows you to override access methods.